# how many keys can I retrieve with one call using chrome.storage.local.get?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I have written a simple chrome extension which is pretty much consisting of a popup, the content page and an html page (called 'report') that the extension itself will populate with data when clicking a specific button on the popup.

Long story short, there's a moment when I need to send 2 differents var from the content script to the reports page. I'm using **chrome.storage.local.get** for this purpose, but it seems that I'm able to retrieve only one of the 2 keys I'm passing.

Here's the code **from the content script**:

```
// first part of script where I define what rankingArray and logsArray are

function saveLogs() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({
        ranking: rankingArray
    }, function() {
        console.log("chrome.storage.local.set on rankingArray");
      });

    chrome.storage.local.set({
        logs: logsArray
    }, function() {
        console.log("chrome.storage.local.set on logsArray");
      });
}
```

and here's the code from the **report.js** page (acting, obviously, on report.html):

```
function getRecords() {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['ranking', 'logs'], function(result){
        var obj = result.ranking;
        var test = result.logs + "";
        console.log('logs:\n' + test);  // this one actually print on the console of report.html
        console.log('ranking:\n' + obj); // this one returns empty ('ranking:   ')
        // more stuff to do with obj and test
    });
    console.log("end of - @getRecords()");
}
```

so I checked the key names and everything several time but I can't figure out what's preventing this from working. 
My doubt now is this: is it correct to use chrome.storage.local.get the way I'm doing? Can it retrieve 2 different set of values at the same time?

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but you can update both keys in one call to `set()`.

Comment: actually I tried that at the beginning but couldn't make it work - reason was a spelling mistake, but I already did split the call to set() when I noticed it so I left it that way

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` show?

Comment: Haven't tried that - should it return the key names?

Comment: It should show the whole object with all the keys and values. Simpler than all that extracting and formatting.

Comment: Simply set both keys in one `set`. Also don't use `+` in console.log, use `,`.

Comment: so, I tried both, this is the outcome:
1 - printing `console.log(results)` I found that the rankingArray seems to be passed, but it is actually an empty array (I need to double check my code, but I'm pretty sure it should not be empty at that point);
2 - for some reason (maybe I'm using the wrong syntax?) if I try to pass both keys in one `set` both keys return undefined - this is how I wrote it
`chrome.storage.local.set([{
        ranking: rankingArray,
        logs: logsArray
    }], function() {
        console.log("records stored with chrome.storage.local");
      });`

Comment: Regarding point 1: I just tried to put a control check in  the content page,`console.log(rankingArray)` the very last moment before passing it - on the content page the array is there as expected, but when I try to restore it on the report.html page it is empty

Comment: my bad - just found the issue, I had my script reloading the content page before reaching the instructions were rankingArray was filled - now I fixed and everything seems to work fine. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question can be closed - as per my comment above the issue was caused by a mistake in the script logic. Basically I had my script reloading the content page before reaching the instructions were rankingArray was filled - once fixed that everything worked as expected.